# Whats is the difference between flex-basis: auto and flex-basis: content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have been reading [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) on `flex-basis` css property. There I don't see any definition of `flex-basis: auto`. It explains about `flex-basis: content`. Seems like `content` has now replaced `auto`. But if that's the case, then why is `auto` still the initial value?

Comment: This is a top hit on google. The question is clear and makes sense. This question is NOT answered on SO - the "duplicate" questions each only answer half of it, with different partial answers in each case.

Answer (score 3):

The [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) seems to have been updated since this question was originally asked. In short:

- `auto` means "look at my width or height property".
- `content` means "look at my content".

This does result in slight differences when the element has a fixed `width` or `height`. You will notice this difference if you view this [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ftna3gx1/33/) ONLY in Firefox (The value `content` is [ONLY supported in Firefox](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_flex-basis_content) at the time of this writing).

Also to quote historical notes from the same MDN article:

> - Originally, flex-basis:auto meant "look at my width or height property".
> - Then, flex-basis:auto was changed to mean automatic sizing, and "main-size" was introduced as the "look at my width or height property" keyword. It was implemented in bug 1032922.
> - Then, that change was reverted in bug 1093316, so auto once again means "look at my width or height property"; and a new content keyword is being introduced to trigger automatic sizing. (bug 1105111 covers adding that keyword).